# Graphical representation of SQL Server tables data in web application using C# or javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, data-representation

I have two tables in database `Projects` & `TeamMembers`

**Projects** table:

```
ProjectName  | Team member
-------------+----------------
ProjectOne   | Member1
ProjectOne   | Member2
ProjectOne   | Member3
ProjectOne   | Member4
```

**TeamMembers** table:

```
TeamMember | Projects
-----------+-------------
Member1    | ProjectOne
Member2    | ProjectOne
Member3    | ProjectOne
Member1    | ProjectTwo
Member2    | ProjectTwo
Member3    | ProjectThree
```

I need to represent this data graphically so that it can display pictorially the various connections each team member has for different projects.

eg:- Member1 and Member2 are connected to both ProjectOne and ProjectTwo this connections sould be evident when they see the picture.

I looked at graphviz but there I need to supply the diagram relationship, but my relationships are not static they are dynamic depending on the data so I was not completely convinced about that approach.

The solution could be a pure server-side code c# or in java-script or Jquery, but should be easy to integrate in asp.net web application

Comment: look at d3.js, might suit you

Comment: http://visjs.org/examples/network/nodeStyles/icons.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used d3.js and was able to solve my question.

Thank you all for your responses.